# ubuntu libraries, libgc.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: apt, package-management, libraries

i just make a new server in vultr with Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-78-generic x86_64), and when i run [my binary app](https://github.com/codenoid/ficha),

```
$ chmod +x ficha
$ ./ficha
$ ./ficha: error while loading shared libraries: libgc.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

i've been try to do this command

```
$ sudo apt-get install libgc1c2:i386
$ sudo apt-get install libgc1c2
$ sudo apt-get install libgc-dev
```

and still error.
dpkg -L libgc1c2 command

```
root@vultr:/home/ficha# dpkg -L libgc1c2
/.
/usr
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgc.so.1.0.3
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgccpp.so.1.0.3
/usr/share  
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/libgc1c2
/usr/share/doc/libgc1c2/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/libgc1c2/README.environment.gz
/usr/share/doc/libgc1c2/copyright
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgc.so.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgccpp.so.1
```

what should i do ?, thanks

Comment: same as like this, i think my app pointed to wrong lib directory , like this error, installed, but app cant found, https://sourceforge.net/p/boomerang/discussion/595266/thread/62057a96/#3412/09bf

Comment: I had similar error while trying to install w3m in Ubuntu 20.04. The following solved it. `sudo apt-get install libgc-dev`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The repo has libgc1c2 on my system too. If you are aware of differences between to versions can you try creating symlink of libgc.so.1 as libgc.so.2
If you find source code for libgc.so.2 you can compile it on your system and deploy to library path